# Shuttle SG31G2V2 Intel Socket T(LGA775) Intel G31 Motherboard Model?

Tags: motherboard

Can anyone tell me what is the Intel motherboard model for this shuttle bare bone kit?

I know the chipset is G31 but for drivers from Intel what is the exact model number for this system?

[Shuttle Computer SG31G2V2](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16856101037)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Shuttle designs their own motherboards. IF you bought the SG31 new, there is a CD in the box with the drivers. If you got it second hand, the drivers are on Shuttles site. Don't forget to update the BIOS too. Older ones do not support all the latest Core2Duo and Core2Quad models.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a shuttle brand motherboard using an intel chipset.

[Sg31G2 V2](http://global.shuttle.com/product_detail_spec.jsp?PI=1267) on their site. "The Shuttle XPC Glamor SG31G2 V2 is designed based on Intel® G31 Express Chipset supporting the 45nm Intel® Core™ 2 multi-core processors. "

I think you will need to get the drivers from shuttle. [Download Link](http://global.shuttle.com/download.jsp) They definitely have chipset drivers available for that model.

There is something to be said that this may be more of a superuser.com question.